# Python - obtain JSON from URL, control and special characters inside

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have been trying to obtain a JSON from a URL with a typical method such as:

```
import urllib.request, json 
with urllib.request.urlopen("my_url") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
```

Nevertheless this fails with `JSONDecodeError` since there is a control character inside some bracket

```
{..."\tvalue"...}
```

I DID modify my source data to not include control characters (something I might not always be able to do), and nevertheless python keeps saying the control character is there.

I decided to take my url response into a string, and there replace inner control characters

```
my_str = url.read()
my_str = my_str.replace('"\\t','"')
```

But in this way, the special characters throughout the JSON file get replaced in odd ways: `{...sábado...}` becomes `{...sa\cxx\c1bado}` or something like that.

How can I sanitize my JSON input from control characters without destroying my special characters?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, forgot to mention something given the first answer:

I did try adding `strict=False`, but then my JSON went... well, nuts. The double quotes became single quotes, and some of them would dissapear, so when I would print it, I got something like:

```
{
    'some_key':'some_value',
    'another_key':'another_value_without_closing_quote,
    a_key_without_opening_quote': 'value'
}
```

Not a single clue of why was that the case.

Comment: why not tell the site that they are generating invalid json? the right answer is to get correctly generated json.... I retract this comment given the top answer

Comment: Don't escape the backslash in your `replace()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving my predicament by first reading the original JSON into a string. There, I would make the string go through a sanitizing method that would remove escape characters and would replace 'damaged' characters for their original special characters.

Answer (score 3):

You can allow control characters by specifying `strict=False`.

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder):

> If `strict` is `False` (`True` is the default), then control characters will be allowed inside strings. Control characters in this context are those with character codes in the 0–31 range, including `'\t'` (tab), `'\n'`, `'\r'` and `'\0'`.

```
data = json.loads(url.read().decode(), strict=False)
```

Comment: lol i didnt even know you could do this :P +1 great answer i love learning new stuff

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried that as well.